# Can't draw my circle from mouse coordinates on click in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a red circle where my mouse clicks but nothing is drawn. I can follow my x,y coordinates being the ones I click. If I put constant values for x,y in the arc method a circle is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
           var currColor = "#FF0000";
              var currSize = 20;

             window.onload = function() {
            var theCanvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
            theCanvas.addEventListener("click", CircleOnClick, false);
        }

            function Cell(row, column) {
                    this.row = row;
                    this.column = column;
                    }

               function getCursorPosition(e) {

var x;
var y;
if (e.pageX != undefined && e.pageY != undefined) {
x = e.pageX;
y = e.pageY;
}
else {
x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
var cell = new Cell(x, y);

return cell;
                }

                function CircleOnClick(e) {



var canvasElement = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
            if (canvasElement && canvasElement.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
                if (ctx) {

                    var cell = getCursorPosition(e);
                    var x = parseInt(cell.row);
                    var y = parseInt(cell.column);

                    //Start drawing
                    ctx.fillStyle=currColor;
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    console.log("x" + x);
                    console.log("y" + y);
                    console.log("Current color" + currColor);
                    console.log("Current size" + currSize);
                    ctx.arc(x,y,currSize,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();

                }
            }

                        }
```

Comment: In what browser doesn't it work?

Comment: I have tested your code in Internet Explorer 9, Chrome 12.0 and Firefox 5.0 and it works fine in all.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, works fine when you put in constant values but when replaceing the constant values in the arc function with values nothing is written.

Answer (score 1):

Using [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/), this would take something like 10 lines:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px dotted #ccc"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
canvas.observe('mouse:up', function(e) {
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(e.memo.e);
  canvas.add(
    new fabric.Circle({ 
      radius: 10, 
      left: pointer.x, 
      top: pointer.y, 
      fill: 'red', 
      selectable: false
    }));
});
```

Here's a [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aAwy/).

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to include fabric.js library. https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Are you sure that your HTML `canvas` element has an `id="my_canvas"` attribute?

Or could you show your HTML code too?

If you are testing in Internet Explorer 9, your HTML document must start with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and you must also comment out your `console.log` rows unless you have the Developer Tools enabled (F12):

```
            ctx.fillStyle=currColor;
            ctx.beginPath();
            //console.log("x" + x);
            //console.log("y" + y);
            //console.log("Current color" + currColor);
            //console.log("Current size" + currSize);
            ctx.arc(x,y,currSize,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
```

Comment: <canvas id="my_canvas" width="800" height="800">
  <p> Your browser does not support HTML5 canvas </p>
  </canvas>

Comment: @Sandra: That looks good, and it works good for me in all browsers I have.